# How to add html email code template to javascript to send personalized mails using googlesheet

Tags: html, google-apps-script, gmail

Hello friends at SOF am new here i have an issue i believe can be sorted here. Am am using google sheet to send email. I have a working code that is sending personalized emails to individual using google sheet and it works fine. the issue is that i want to add an html email template to the message instead of just plan text. Here is a picture of my setup below which is working fine presently but dont know how to add my html email template code to it as the mail message body. I marked the message body in yellow i want to replace that message with my html email code template. I also place sample codes for you to copy and try out you only need create the google spreadsheet and put emails field at your end to test execution.

[VIEW SHEET AND SCRIPT FILE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiaKN.jpg)

[VIEW HTML EMAIL CODE TEMPLATE HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zA_4FMrf40q_4SyokyPtzXtcwHHUkWX5/view?usp=sharing)

```js
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // Start at second row because the first row contains the data labels
  var numRows = 3; // Put in here the number of rows you want to process

  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B4
  // Column A = Email Address, Column B = First Name
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
   var row = data[i];
   var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column of selected data
   var message = "Hey " + row[1] + ",\n how are you doing today?"; // Assemble the body text
   var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can send HTML using htmlBody as the Advanced parameters. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options

Comment: Thanks for the reply where do i declare this am new to scripting i tried this with htmlBody earlier but its like not properly declared so it picks the html codes as error.

Comment: For example, you can send HTML like ``MailApp.sendEmail({to: emailAddress, subject: subject, body: message, htmlBody: html})``. In this case, if HTML cannot be load when ``htmlBody`` is used, ``body`` is used. And can we see the script that you tried? If you can do, please update your question. I think that it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: please can you possibly code an example adding some html to the message body so i can try it at my end

Comment: I couldn't understand your comment. I'm sorry for my poor English skill. If your issue was solved, I'm glad.